# Can't figure out how to retrieve values from heap in MIPS (MARS)

Tags: heap-memory, mips, mars-simulator

I am new to using dynamic memory in mips. I have to create a program that takes 2 integers from the user, find the positions where the binary forms of those numbers have a 1, print the positions for each number/set (For example: 1000 1001 1100 0000 0000 0010 1000 1110 corresponds to the set: {2, 3, 4, 8, 10, 23, 24, 25, 28, 32}). Then take another integer from the user and see if it is one of the positions in either set. Eventually I will have to find the union and intersection of the two sets but I am not there yet.

So I printed out both sets normally but I also saved them to heap because I figured that would be the only way to be access them later to see if the next number is a member of either set. My problem is that, for the life of me, I can't figure out how to retrieve the sets from heap to use them again.

My code is below. I know it is kind of long so for reference, I store them in dynamic memory in the SetOne and SetTwo functions, and I am trying to retrieve them in the ElementSetOne and ElementSetTwo functions. Sorry if I'm not being descriptive enough, I'm still very new to StackOverflow. Thanks.

```
.data                   #Data section

Prompt1: .asciiz "\nEnter first number: "
Prompt2: .asciiz "\nEnter second number: "
Result1: .asciiz "\nMembers of Set 1: "
Result2: .asciiz "\nMembers of Set 2: "
Prompt3: .asciiz "\nEnter an element to find: "
Result3: .asciiz "\nIt is a member of set 1"
Result4: .asciiz "\nIt is not a member of set 1"
Result5: .asciiz "\nIt is a member of set 2"
Result6: .asciiz "\nIt is not a member of set 2"
Result7: .asciiz "\nUnion of the sets: "
Result8: .asciiz "\nIntersection of the sets: "
Prompt4: .asciiz "\nDo you want to compute set functions again? "

.globl main

.text                   #Code section

main:
li $v0, 4       #system call code for Print String
la $a0, Prompt1     #load address of Prompt1 into $a0
syscall         #print the Prompt1 message

li $v0, 5       #system call code for Read Integer
syscall         #reads the value of 1st integer into $v0
move $t0, $v0       #move first integer to $t0

li $v0, 4       #system call code for Print String
la $a0, Prompt2     #load address of Prompt2 into $a0
syscall         #print the Prompt2 message

li $v0, 5       #system call code for Read Integer
syscall         #reads the value of second integer into $v0
move $t1, $v0       #move second integer to $t1

First:
li $v0, 4       #System call code for Print String
la $a0, Result1     #load address of Print into $a0
syscall         #print the string

li $v0, 9       #syscall for dynamic memory allocation (sbrk)
li $a0, 80
syscall
move $s0, $v0

li $t4, 0       #sets count to 0

FirstMask:
beq $t0, 0, Second  #if first set is done, go to second
andi $t6, $t0, 1    #first number and 1
addi $t4, $t4, 1    #increase count by 1
beq $t6, 1, SetOne  #if and with 1, go to SetOne    
srl $t0, $t0, 1     #shift number right 1 position
j FirstMask     #restart loop

SetOne:                 #STORE SET 1
sw $t4, 0($s0)      #store position in memory
add $s0, $s0, 4     #increment memory


li $v0, 1       #system call code for Print Integer
move $a0, $t4       #move value to be printed to $a0
syscall         #print the the count positiom

li $v0, 11          #syscall number for printing character
li $a0, 32      #move ascii code for space in $a0
syscall         #print blank space

srl $t0, $t0, 1     #shift input number right 1 position

j FirstMask

Second:
li $v0, 4       #System call code for Print String
la $a0, Result2     #load address of Print into $a0
syscall         #print the string

li $v0, 9       #syscall for dynamic memory allocation (sbrk)
li $a0, 80
syscall
move $s1, $v0

li $t4, 0       #reset count to 0

SecondMask:
beq $t1, 0, Element #if number is done go to next step
andi $t6, $t1, 1    #and input with 1
addi $t4, $t4, 1    #increase count by 1
beq $t6, 1, SetTwo  #if and with 1, save position number    
srl $t1, $t1, 1     #shift right 1 position

j SecondMask        

SetTwo:                 #STORE SET 2
sw $t4, 0($s1)      #store position in memory
add $s1, $s1, 4     #increment memory

li $v0, 1       #system call code for Print Integer
move $a0, $t4       #move value to be printed to $a0
syscall         #print the count

li $v0, 11          #syscall number for printing character
li $a0, 32      #move ascii code for space into $a0
syscall         #print blank space

srl $t1, $t1, 1     #shift right 1 position

j SecondMask

Element:
li $v0, 4       #System call code for Print String
la $a0, Prompt3     #load address of Print into $a0
syscall         #print the string

li $v0, 5       #system call code for Read Integer
syscall         #reads the value of 1st integer into $v0
move $t2, $v0       #move first integer to $t2

ElementSetOne:          #RETRIEVE SET 1
lw $t3, 0($s0)      #load first number from memory into $t3
beq $t2, $t3, InSetOne  #if element is in memory, go to InSetOne
bgt $s0, 40, NotSetOne  #if element isnt in entire array, go to NotSetOne
addi $s0, $s0, 4    #increment memory by 4

j ElementSetOne

InSetOne:
li $v0, 4       #System call code for Print String
la $a0, Result4     #load address of Print into $a0
syscall         #print the string

j ElementSetTwo

NotSetOne:
li $v0, 4       #System call code for Print String
la $a0, Result5     #load address of Print into $a0
syscall         #print the string

j ElementSetTwo

ElementSetTwo:          #RETREIVE SET 2
lw $t3, 0($s1)      #load first number from memory into $t3
beq $t2, $t3, InSetTwo  #if element is in memory, go to InSetOne
bgt $s1, 40, NotSetTwo  #if element isnt in entire array, go to NotSetOne
addi $s1, $s1, 4    #increment memory by 4
j ElementSetTwo

InSetTwo:
li $v0, 4       #System call code for Print String
la $a0, Result5     #load address of Print into $a0
syscall         #print the string

j Exit

NotSetTwo:
li $v0, 4       #System call code for Print String
la $a0, Result6     #load address of Print into $a0
syscall         #print the string

j Exit

Exit:
li $v0, 10      #terminate program
syscall         #return control to the system
```

**Update:** I am taking programming in C next semester so I don't know very much about the language. Essentially, my problem is that I stored a set of numbers into heap. And I can't figure out how to retrieve them now.

I know they were successfully stored because when I look in the heap section while running the program in MARS, I can see them being stored one by one. I'm just trying to retrieve all the numbers for each set now, but what I have just returns 0. So I'm thinking I must be using the wrong address or I'm missing a step somewhere.

I think this is all the code that is relevant:

```
li $v0, 9           #syscall for dynamic memory allocation (sbrk)
li $a0, 80
syscall
move $s0, $v0

#Theres a loop here to find the values of $t4
SetOne:             #STORE SET 1
sw $t4, 0($s0)      #store values in $s0
add $s0, $s0, 4     #increment memory


li $v0, 9           #syscall for dynamic memory allocation (sbrk)
li $a0, 80
syscall
move $s1, $v0

#Theres another loop here to find different values of $t4
SetTwo:             #STORE SET 2
sw $t4, 0($s1)      #store position in memory
add $s1, $s1, 4     #increment memory

#Then later on I want to retrieve these values so i can use them in other loops

ElementSetOne:
lw $t3, 0($s0)          #load first number from memory into $t3
beq $t2, $t3, InSetOne  #if element is in memory, go to InSetOne
bgt $s0, 40, NotSetOne  #if element isnt in entire array, go to NotSetOne
addi $s0, $s0, 4        #increment memory by 4
j ElementSetOne.        #loop

ElementSetTwo:          #RETREIVE SET 2
lw $t3, 0($s1)          #load first number from memory into $t3
beq $t2, $t3, InSetTwo  #if element is in memory, go to InSetOne
bgt $s1, 40, NotSetTwo  #if element isnt in entire array, go to NotSetOne
addi $s1, $s1, 4        #increment memory by 4
j ElementSetTwo         #loop
```

Comment: What are you having problems with?  Can you describe it in C-like terms: array reference, pointer dereference, for-loop...?

Comment: Does MARS give you a way to view your registers as well? One of the registers might be updated after the `sbrk` syscall to give you a pointer to the desired memory location.